# How to show process manager for nwjs app?

Tags: nwjs

Is there any package available to show process manager for `nwjs`,
or how can I enable the built in task manager(<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> - chrome)?

All I found is [electron-process-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-process-manager) only for electron.